# C language : How to make an char array consists of text(.txt) file letters?

Tags: c

As the title above, I wonder how to save letters of txt file into a char array.

For example, if the text file is

123\n45 678

The char array arr[] what I want to make will be arr[] = {'1','2','3','\n','4','5',' ','6','7','8'}

How to make that array include getting an individual character?

Comment: You could use `fread()` to input with a single call. What have you tried?

Comment: at compile time or run time?

Comment: `fread()` is definitely the correct choice. What do you mean whan you ask _"How to make that array include getting an individual character?"_

Comment: Following @OldProgrammer I often write a small code to generate source code from something else, and then copy/paste the output into the main project. For example `printf("char arr[] = {"); for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("'%c',", arr[i]); printf("};\n");` with extra attention to the newline data in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is to use fgets() function

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int size = 15;
    char arr[size];

    FILE *pf = fopen(".txt", "r");

    fgets(arr, size, pf);

    puts(arr);

fclose(pf);


    return 0;
}
```

fgets prototype:

fgets(char *string, int numberCharToRead, FILE *ptr)

1. It will assign the characters to char array string
2. it will read until numberCharToRead unless it will hit \n before. In that case, it will append the '\0' character at the end of the string
3. ptr points to the address of the file

if there is an error it will return NULL, otherwise it will return a pointer

NOTE: fgets() will not get terminated because a file consists of \n. When fgets is called it will read it as '\','0'

Alternatively, you can minimize allocated memory by using the file size as an array size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    FILE *pf = fopen(".txt", "r");

    int check = fseek(pf, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (check)
    {
        printf("could not fseek\n");
    }
    int size = 0;
    size = ftell(pf);
    fseek(pf, 0, SEEK_SET); /* add this */
    char arr[size];

    fgets(arr, size, pf);

    puts(arr);

    fclose(pf);

    return 0;
}
```